# Am i destroying my pc by mining?

Tags: cpu-mining

I have AMD FX 8350 on msi 970 motherboard. Monero mining seems to be good at 400 H/s. With the stock heat sink and no overclocking will this damage my components or degrade the performance.

Will reducing threads to 4 make it more durable?  (At 4 cores im getting around 350H/s)

Should i buy a better cooling system? Current temp is around 55 to 60 °C

In addition i have a huge air supply. Even though it looks stupid its working. (In the picture)[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running at full utilization is likely to degrade performance, especially for the CPU. It's difficult to say by how much, though.

Luckily, your temperatures are pretty solid at only 60 degrees. This is around the maximum I would recommend for constant use.

Since the 8350 has an 8MB cache, it's actually optimal for you to mine with 8/2 = 4 threads. Any number greater than this is most likely wasted. You can reduce it below 4 to reduce CPU use.